# react-sortable-hoc: Handling of click event on list item

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

This question is about https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc.
I am pretty new to React, so I find the following a bit irritating. Go to
https://jsfiddle.net/7tb7jkz5/. Notice line 4

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => <li className="SortableItem" onClick={console.debug(value)}>{value}</li>);
```

When you run the code, the console will log "Item 0" to "Item 99". A click on an item will log the same, but **three** times. Why does this happen? And is this really necessary or more like a bug?

I expected a behavior similar to an ordinary DOM, so the click event would bubble up from the clicked item and could be caught along the way through its ancestors. The observed behavior looks to me like the click event would be sent down by the list to each list item three times.

**Update:**
Well, this is actually as clear as crystal, thanks for pointing this out, Shubham. I did not just specify a reference, but an actual call to console.debug, which was executed every time the expression was evaluated. Common mistake.

Still, this means, each list item is rendered (I guess) three times, when I click one of them. I suspect missing optimization or even useless redrawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mention the `onClick` action as a `function`. Use `() =>` inside the handler  call. Try the below method, it works although has a very slow response

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => <li className="SortableItem" onClick={() => console.debug(value)}>{value}</li>);
```

Comment: Yep, I suspected something like that. Of course, I did not just specify a reference, but an actual call to console.debug, which was executed every time the expression was evaluated. It's clear, and I was inattentive.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `distance={1}` on SortableContainer component.

Check this link https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/issues/461

```html
const ListItemContainer = SortableContainer((props) => {
  return <listItem />
})

<ListItemContainer               
   onSortEnd={this._orderingFolder}
   lockAxis='y'
   lockToContainerEdges={true}
   lockOffset='0%'
   distance={1}
/>
```

Comment: Elements are getting stuck

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can define and handle click event using react-sortable-hoc: 
please check below code

```
import { SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove } from 'react-sortable-hoc';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ value }) => {

  return (
    <div >
      <div id="button_value">{value}</div>
    </div >
  );
});



const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }) => {
  return (
    <div >
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem
          key={`item-${index}`}
          index={index}
          value={value}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
    };
  }

  onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
    this.setState(({ items }) => ({
      items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    }));
  };

  shouldCancelStart = (e) => {
    var targetEle = e;
    if (!targetEle.id) {
      targetEle = e.target;
    }
    if (targetEle.id === 'button_value') {
      console.log('Div button click here ');
      // perform you click opration here
    }

// you can define multiple click event here using seprate uniq id of html element even you can manage delay on click here also using set timeout and sortmove props and sortend props you need to manage just one boolean flag.


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SortableList
          items={this.state.items}
          onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}
          onSortStart={(_, event) => event.preventDefault()}
          shouldCancelStart={this.shouldCancelStart} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

First define id button_value as in html element and then using this id you can get click event using this props shouldCancelStart

Answer (score 0):

I made the div with the onClick as a button, and onClick worked,

Spent a lot of time figuring it out, There is no need to use distance or pressDelay

[image]